# Geometric Network trace in ArcGIS: trace downstream with loops included

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometric-network, trace

I am looking for a way to make a “**trace downstream**” in a geometric network in ArcGIS **where loops are included too**. With the trace-operation “trace downstream”, the loops are not included.  I know there is a trace-operation **“find loops” but this returns all loops which are connected** (therefore e.g. also the loops upstream the flag). **I only want to receive the loops that are downstream my flag.** The result should be a selection with the result of the trace downstream + just the loops which are downstream the flag. Would you know a way to achieve that in ArcGIS or would you know a good workaround?

*Edit:* manual removing selections is not possible in my case, **an automated solution has to be found**!

*Edit2:* **an ArcGIS-only solution would be preferred.**

Answer (score 3):

RivEX can attribute your river network with loop ID's, see the help file [here](http://www.rivex.co.uk/Online-Manual/Identifyloops.html). You could then use your downstream trace to select polylines, as RivEX gives each loop family a unique ID you could simply summarize that and then re-select based upon your list of ID's.

So this is a partial automated solution, use RivEX to encode your network then use what ever you want to automate the rest.

Comment: thank you very much. Would you know an "ArcGIS core-product solution" too?